# Fastest sum of absolute values of 32 differences

Tags: java, performance, bitwise, integer

A `long` should be treated as a list of 32 unsigned numbers, each of them just two bit long. So `0x1234F...` represents

```
{0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 3, ...}
```

and `0x55AA0...` represents

```
{1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, ...}
```

Given two such lists, I need to compute the absolute values of the pairwise differences and sum them up. To continue the example, the difference list would be

```
{-1, 0, -1, 1, -2, 1, -1, -2, 3, 3, ...}
```

Now just drop the sign and sum it up. What I did is

```
static int funnySum(long x, long y) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<32; ++i) {
        int xNum = (int) (x & 3);
        int yNum = (int) (y & 3);
        result += Math.abs(xNum - yNum);

        x >>= 2;
        y >>= 2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

It's the taxicab-distance computing algorithm used in [this question of mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/87292/14363). It occurred to me that it can be done without any loop, however I haven't figured the details out yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These sorts of problems are a fun challenge, and you are right, shifting is a great solution. I have played with it, and can get up to 5X performance improvements by applying a few tricks.

The first trick, is to split the long values up in to collections of independent 2-bit groups... in bits, it would be the two groups:

```
00xx00xx00xx00xx.....00xx00xx
xx00xx00xx00xx00.....xx00xx00
```

by taking these alternate groups, there's some tricks we can play. For a start, we can do some bit manipulation and arithmetic on the 2-bit groups without overflowing in to the neighbours (because the neighbour is at least 2 bits away).

Additionally, we can shift the second part by two bits, and use the exact same code to process the second part... it's easier to show, than to explain... but, more explanation first...

With the 2-bit blocks, we can turn the `a - b` in to `a + (-b)` using two's compliment. To do this, we take our 2-bit number and make it a 3-bit number (it's OK, we have the space because our neighbour is far away...).

So, our `b` bits become a 3-bit 2's compliment:

```
00 -> 000
01 -> 111
10 -> 110
11 -> 101
```

We then add that to our `a` bits, using  regular addition. Some of these may overflow in to the 4th bit, but we will truncate that overflow. For example, if the a-bits were `11` and the b-bits were `10`, the whole process is:

```
start
a  0011
b  0010

b's 2's comp
a  0011
b' 0110

add a+b'
a  0011
b' 0110
s  1001
```

now we truncate the overflow to leave a 3-bit value of:

```
s   001
```

which is the difference.

Note that the math is more complicated if the b value is larger (a negative result). Compare the above with a `10` and b `11`:

```
start
a  0010
b  0011

b's 2's comp
a  0010
b' 0101

add a+b'
a  0010
b' 0101
s  0111
```

Now `s` (the sum), is truncated back to 3 bits, and the sign bit is set, and the difference is thus `-1`.

If the value is negative, we negate it back to positive (abs value). This can be done by running the 2's compliment again if the value is negative.

This all sounds awfully complicated, but, the point is that, in a long, you can do 16 2-bit processes at the same time... here's the code:

```
private static final long COMP      = 0x1111111111111111L;
private static final long TWOBITS   = 0x3333333333333333L;
private static final long THREEBITS = 0x7777777777777777L;
private static final long SIGNBIT   = 0x4444444444444444L;
private static final long FOURSET   = 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fL;


static long twoBitDiff(final long x, long y) {
    // two's compliment on 2-bit sets of y - to make 3bit values.
    // third bit is the sign bit.
    y &= TWOBITS;
    y ^= THREEBITS;
    y += COMP;

    long diff =  (x & TWOBITS) + y;

    // negate any negative results - (abs value)
    // two's complement again
    long sign = (diff & SIGNBIT) >>> 2;
    diff ^= sign | (sign << 1);
    diff += sign;
    return diff & TWOBITS;

}
```

So, the above method will calculate the difference between the value on alternating 2-bit blocks, leaving the difference at their relative positions in the output.

Put this together with a control-method, that first computes the differences on one set of 2-bits, then the other set of 2-bits, and efficiently adds up the results:

```
static int shiftySum(long x, long y) {

    long diff = twoBitDiff(x, y) + twoBitDiff(x >>> 2, y >>> 2);

    diff += diff >>> 4;
    // ensure low-order unused bits are clean.
    diff &= FOURSET;
    diff += diff >>> 8;
    diff += diff >>> 16;
    diff += diff >>> 32;
    return (int)(diff & 0xff);
}
```

Running the above through some performance benchmarks, comparing the funnySum with the shiftySum, and maaartySum, and now freakySum, I get the performance results:

```
Task TBSums -> Funny: (Unit: MILLISECONDS)
  Count    :      136      Average  :  36.8288
  Fastest  :  35.8241      Slowest  :  46.3444
  95Pctile :  38.5454      99Pctile :  41.3839
  TimeBlock : 37.836 37.312 36.661 36.396 36.788 36.555 36.394 36.482 36.212 37.607
  Histogram :   136

Task TBSums -> Freaky: (Unit: MILLISECONDS)
  Count    :      833      Average  :   6.0031
  Fastest  :   5.7492      Slowest  :  14.5596
  95Pctile :   6.2877      99Pctile :   8.4362
  TimeBlock : 5.941 5.871 5.890 5.872 5.888 6.282 6.128 6.061 6.051 6.050
  Histogram :   832     1

Task TBSums -> Shifty: (Unit: MILLISECONDS)
  Count    :      857      Average  :   5.8345
  Fastest  :   5.5854      Slowest  :  11.3062
  95Pctile :   6.1534      99Pctile :   7.7529
  TimeBlock : 5.800 5.663 5.771 5.701 5.740 5.995 5.929 5.838 5.912 5.999
  Histogram :   854     3

Task TBSums -> Maaarty: (Unit: MILLISECONDS)
  Count    :     1000      Average  :   3.6067
  Fastest  :   3.4531      Slowest  :   6.9772
  95Pctile :   3.8111      99Pctile :   4.5753
  TimeBlock : 3.581 3.510 3.522 3.524 3.698 3.672 3.641 3.655 3.658 3.606
  Histogram :   999     1
```

There is something to be said for maaartinus's new implementation...

Comment: I edited my code to fix the bug if you want to repeat your profiling.

Comment: My code is just fixed version of ratchet's idea [plus an old trick](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/52331/14363).

Answer (score 5):

We can try to optimize the subtraction by looking at the result table and finding a bit level hack that gives us the right result after which a modified bitcount will produce the result.

The table when viewed for each bit pair is:

```
        00 01 10 11
        0  1  2  3 

00 0    0  1  2  3
01 1    1  0  1  2
10 2    2  1  0  1
11 3    3  2  1  0
```

`a^b` is *almost* the right result, only for a=1 and b=2 does this give the wrong result (3 instead of 1).

So that need to be detected and dealt with.

That means that if `a&b == 0` and `a^b == 3` and both a and b are not 0 then the result should be 1 which we can do by xoring the high bit of the result.

```
long result = a^b;
long is3 = result & result << 1; //high bit per pair will contain whether the pair is 3
is3 &= 0xaaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaal; //extract the high bit per pair
long is0 = a&b;
is0 = ~(is0 | is0 << 1);//high bit per pair will contain whether the pair is 0
is0 &= 0xaaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaal; //extract the high bit per pair
long notBoth0 = (a|a<<1) & (b|b<<1);
notBoth0 &= 0xaaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaal; //extract the high bit per pair
result ^= is3 & is0 & notBoth0; // only invert the bits set in is3, is0 and notBoth0
```

The other selection possibility is when the bits in a are not equal:

```
long result = a^b;
long is3 = result & result << 1; //high bit per pair will contain whether the pair is 3
is3 &= 0xaaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaal; //extract the high bit per pair
long isEq = a^(a<<1);
isEq &= 0xaaaa_aaaa_aaaa_aaaal; //extract the high bit per pair
result ^= is3 & isEq0; // only invert the bits set in is3 and isEq0
```

The modified bitcount would be something like:

```
result = (result & 0x3333_3333_3333_3333l) + ((result >>  2) & 0x3333_3333_3333_3333l);
result = (result & 0x0f0f_0f0f_0f0f_0f0fl) + ((result >>  4) & 0x0f0f_0f0f_0f0f_0f0fl);
result = (result & 0x00ff_00ff_00ff_00ffl) + ((result >>  8) & 0x00ff_00ff_00ff_00ffl);
result = (result & 0x0000_ffff_0000_ffffl) + ((result >> 16) & 0x0000_ffff_0000_ffffl);
result = (result & 0x0000_0000_ffff_ffffl) + ((result >> 32) & 0x0000_0000_ffff_ffffl);
```

<sup>note: I use underscores in the hexadecimal literals to make it clearer (they are legal in java 7 I believe) however in java 6 you will need to remove them.</sup>

Comment: There's bug there: `a&b == 0` holds also for `a==0` and `b==3`, which you wanted to exclude. Nonetheless, the idea is good and it works after my fix (to be posted soon).

Comment: @maaartinus oops missed it. I added the fix in my code now as well

Comment: Note that this code is giving me 96 (instead of 94) for the inputs `a=-9223372036854775808` and `b=9223372036854775807` -> See [ideone here](http://ideone.com/SRIR9a)

Comment: @rolfl found&fixed the error. That what I get by debugging without running the code.

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer ratchet's solution as it looks simple, but currently there's a bug. Reading rolfl's solution brought me to how to fix it. That's my take so far....

```
private static final long HIGH = 0xAAAA_AAAA_AAAA_AAAAL;

int maaartySum(long x, long y) {
    final long xor = x^y;
    // high bit per pair will contain whether the pair is 3, low bit is garbled
    final long is3 = xor & (xor << 1);

    // high bit per pair will contain whether the pair is non-zero, low bit is garbled
    final long x2 = x | (x << 1);
    final long y2 = y | (y << 1);

    // high bit per pair will contain whether both pairs are non-zero, low bit is garbled
    final long is0 = x2 & y2;

    // high bit per pair will contain whether the pairs need correction, low bit is 0
    final long isBoth = (is3 & is0) & HIGH;
    final long val = xor ^ isBoth; // only invert the bits set in both is3 and is0

    // count the high bits twice
    return Long.bitCount(val) + Long.bitCount(val & HIGH);
}
```